# How to increase font size in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to increase following telephone number font size.

```
<div class="topbar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <p class="pull-left hidden-xs"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i><span>Mon - Sat 8.30AM - 5.00PM. Sunday CLOSED</span></p>
                <p class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>Tel No. (+77) 853 740 966</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should look at the bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#type

Comment: So what CSS have you tried? Seems pretty basic. And what do you mean by increasing the "telephone number size" and font size? I know what the font size is, but what's the "telephone number size"?

Comment: Do you want to increase only the font size of everything in element `<p class="pull-right">`?

Answer (score 19):

Wrap it in span and add css to it:

```css
.text-large {
  font-size: 150%;
}
```

```html
<div class="topbar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <p class="pull-left hidden-xs"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i><span>Mon - Sat 8.30AM - 5.00PM. Sunday CLOSED</span></p>
        <p class="pull-right text-large"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i><span>Tel No. (+77) 853 740 966</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need increase telephone icon also

Comment: In that case add `text-large` class to `<p>` element that contains both icon and telephone number. Edited my answer

Answer (score 7):

Update: `<big>` is supposed to be deprecated in HTML5, so CSS is the only way. Using a relative size works best no matter what the current font size is.

```
.font-size-lg { font-size: 1.2rem; }
```

---

I haven't found an easy way with Bootstrap, so I use `<big>`.

```
<p class="pull-right">
  <big><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>Tel No. (+77) 853 740 966</big>
</p>
```

I wish there was a Bootstrap class so I don't have to use an extra line in HAML.

```
%p
  %big This is bigger.
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<span style="font-size:30px">Tel No. (+77) 853 740 966</span>
```

Or

```
.large-fontsize{
font-size: 30px !important;
}  

<span class="large-fontsize">Tel No. (+77) 853 740 966</span>
```

Comment: pixels for size is a terrible solution because of responsiveness. On a mobile those pixels can create different sizes than on desktop. em is a better measurement or percentage is a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using SCSS of similar to generate your CSS, you can add your own global class that slightly increases (+25%) the font size.

In the _variables.scss found in the Bootstrap bundle there is a variable already defined $font-size-lg. Use it to define a class in your own style.scss (or similar) in your project.

```
.font-size-lg {
  font-size: $font-size-lg;
}
```

Use it in HTML

```
<span class="font-size-lg">Text to enlarge</span>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can always bypass bootstrap and edit the font size at the source in-line:

```
style="font-size:x-large;"
```